# How to adapt my css code to all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to animate the joining of two text halves. I came up with this code, but it doesn't adapt to different screen sizes, what can I do to fix it ?

```css
.ab {
position: relative;
animation-name: ab;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count:1;
animation-direction: alternate;}

@keyframes ab {
  0% {left:0px;  top:0px;}
  25% { left:350px; top: 0px;}

}

.ba {
text-align : right;
position: relative;
animation-name: ba;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count:1;
animation-direction: alternate;}

@keyframes ba {
  0% { right:0px;  top:0px;}
  25% {right:350px; top: 0px;}

}

.column{    
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
<div class="ab column"> Bienvenue </div>
<div class="ba column"> deuxieme </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you used vw unit instead of px?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a responsive unit of measure. px is not one of those. I used `%` in my example here:

Watch out: I had to use `transform: translate` to fully align the absolute positioned items.

```css
// this ACTUALLY centers the element
.absolute-item{
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0); // translate(x, y)
}
```

```css
.row{
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position:relative;
}

.column{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.ab{
  color: green;
  animation: ab 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.ba{
  color: red;
  animation: ba 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes ab {
  0% {
    left: 5%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

@keyframes ba {
  0% {
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="ab column">Bienvenue</div>
  <div class="ba column">deuxieme</div>
</div>
```